# Cocoa Application does not redraw after overlapping another application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, drawrect

After I overlay an application over my previous application, I go back to previous application and encounter a few errors:

- certain components have disappeared
- only way to make the components visible is to resize the window
- that seems to redraw the whole canvas.

---

1. Weird thing is that there are only a couple of components and drawn images that are missing
2. It doesn't always happen but only a couple of times
3. I haven't found a solid way to reproduce the problem.

Anybody have an Idea why this is happening?

Comment: How are these components/images drawn?  If you want to progress this with Apple you'll need a sample app that shows the problem; can you provide one?  (it'll be useful anyway - I currently have a CALayer artifact issue which I cannot reproduce in the sample app!)

Comment: is it possible to simulate a resize by code?

Comment: You can just call `[self setFrameSize:size]` I would imagine.

Comment: Do you have any custom drawing in the app? Does the app appear sluggish when the prob happens prob signifying a memory issue?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced exactly the same issue (view was updated correctly only after resizing), except that I've used OpenGL drawing in OSX game.

My problem was solved by adding this:

```
GLint vblSynch = 1;
[[self openGLContext] setValues:&vblSynch forParameter:NSOpenGLCPSwapInterval];
```

in my custom NSOpenGLView init method.
Then I've implemented:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [self destroyFramebuffer]; // glDeleteFramebuffers..
    [self createFramebuffer];  // [super prepareOpenGl], glGenFrame(Render)Buffers, bind buffers, etc
    [self drawView]; // [[self openGLContext] makeCurrentContext], make some drawing, [[self openGLContext] flushBuffer]..
}
```

like this.

After these changes, when window gets focus it redraws itself (without any resizing stuff :) ).

Hope this helps!

Comment: thx for the insight but its not an openGL app, I just did the the quick fix that when my window becomes active it will resize, its not pretty but it works

Comment: Anyway, I think you should look into your drawRect method. Good luck!